# Puzzle #7: Thrown for a Loupe

Tags: logical-deduction

Five magnifying glasses have been laid out on a table. Let's call them A, B, C, D, and E, with A on the left, B next to it, and so on. The lenses have different magnifications, these being 2x, 4x, 8x, 16x and 32x magnification.

Using the hints below, can you order them, from strongest to weakest magnification?

> - D is four times stronger than E
> - The weakest magnifying glass is not C or E
> - C has 8x magnification
> - A has weaker magnification than E
> - B has stronger magnification than D

Comment: This is my first time making this sort of puzzle, so sorry if the clues are too vague or too easy.

Comment: I liked this puzzle. I think I figured it out... but @JonMarkPerry got it before I did, so he deserves the tick. Either way, I found the puzzle quite fun! DVL3 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: I'm downvoting because 2 of the clues are unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> B, D, C, E, A

because:

> Clue 3 tells us C is 8x. Clue 1 now tells us D is 16x and also that E is 4x. Only two magnifying glasses, A and B, now remain, and we can use either that A is therefore 2x from clue 4, or that B is 32x from clue 5.

Comment: Correct, sorry if that was easy

Comment: nah it was great! clue 2 is redundant btw.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: After applying clue 3, clue 1 is already sufficient to place D and E.

Comment: The editing following my previous comment has introduced a false statement. Clue 1 says four times, not eight times.

Comment: couldn't read a Q about optics! fixed. @PeterTaylor